# Media queries not working on mobile phone

Tags: css, media-queries

I am working on my own website with self-made `media-queries`.

**DEMO:** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CB57U/2/)

**IMAGE EXAMPLE (mobile screen)**

[image: Error media queries]

As you can see it works fine on deskopt, but I dont know why on mobile displays high resolution .

Any clue?

**MEDIA QUERIES USED:**

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 700px) {}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px)  {}
@media only screen and (max-width: 880px)  {}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px)  {}
```

Viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Note: Yes, I know I am not following the standars, but shouldn't be the problem (sure?)

Comment: What's the resolution of the mobile from which you took this screenshot?

Comment: Max resolution: 854px×480px

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame to me say this, but the problem was on the mediaqueries sintaxis.

**I just forgot the ending tag "}"**, so modern browsers understands where it ends, but not the mobile ones.